# I'm thinking of upgrading Office 2013 Home and Student to version 2021, but have concerns

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm still using Microsoft Office Home and Student 2013, mainly just for Word 2013, and happy with it. I recently saw a good price in a Memorial Day sale on HP for the newest version, Microsoft Office Home and Student 2021 ($99.99) and I’m thinking of upgrading just because I haven’t done it in ten years, but I have serious reservations.

1. Will installing the 2021 version leave my previous installation of Microsoft Office Home and Student 2013 intact? It would be a big help in migration and give me a chance to fix what 2021 breaks.
2. I understand you need a Microsoft Account to download it, but I want to use it completely offline and save all my files locally, like I’ve been doing for the past 40 years.
3. Can I import and get all the customizations out of my 2013 Normal template?
4. Will I be able to get my customizations, custom Ribbon tabs and Ribbon groups?
5. Custom template that adds right-click autocorrect items
6. Import my Macros
7. I’ve been using DOCX and will this force a new file format on me?

The last time I upgraded was from Word XP (2002) to Word 2013 and boy was that a shock and disappointment. Ten years later and I’m still not a fan of the barely customizable Ribbon. It took me over a year to get Word 2013 into a form I was comfortable with and I still miss the unlimited interface customization options I had previously in Word 2002.

**EDIT May 29, 2022**
I decided to just dive in and install 2021. I am happy to report none of my concerns materialized. It just added a new skin to my old Word.The shock this time was how little the upgrade changed the program after ten years.

Comment: You can typically get a thirty-day trial period for free, and install it in parallel to investigate and verify your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The step from Office XP to 2013 would have been a major shock. Office 2021 uses the same .docx format but there have been tweaks.

I have somewhat different answers.

> 1. Will installing the 2021 version leave my previous installation of Microsoft Office Home and Student 2013 intact? It would be a big help
>    in migration and give me a chance to fix what 2021 breaks.

You can add Office 2021 to your computer without uninstalling Office 2013. These should have different locations for your user templates folder location. I currently have Office 2010 and 365 on my computer without problems. I have had Office 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 and 365 on the same computer without problems.

> 2. I understand you need a Microsoft Account to download it, but I want to use it completely offline and save all my files locally, like
>    I’ve been doing for the past 40 years.

With Office 2021 (but not 365) you can do this. With both you can save your files completely offline, however Office 365 requires monthly Internet connection; Office 2021 does not require even that.)

> 3. Can I import and get all the customizations out of my 2013 Normal template?

Yes. The simplest method is to copy the normal template from your user templates folder for 2013 into the one for 2021 and then update the file by opening it and under File > Info clicking on the button to update it.

Note that not all customizations are stored in the normal template. See [Word 2007 and later key data file locations](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/13675-word-2007-later-key-data-file-locations.html).

> 4. Will I be able to get my customizations, custom Ribbon tabs and Ribbon groups?

Yes. If your customizations are done through the UI Export them in Word 2013 and import in Word 2021. I much prefer to store my customizations in much more durable files, but it takes a bit more thought.

- [Customize the Ribbon (It doesn't take rocket science)](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html) by Greg Maxey.
- [Modifying the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)](https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm) - my page

> 5. Custom template that adds right-click autocorrect items

I am unsure what we are discussing. There are lots of things done by AutoCorrect. Word replaced the spell-check dialog with the Editor. See [my article on the Microsoft site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/classic-spell-check-dialog-macro-to-use-to-get/a53fff0c-f15d-4150-95d6-1724c6ddca91) about using the classic spell-check dialog instead or in addition to the Editor.

Right-clicking on a spelling error does let you add the correction to AutoCorrect, if that is what you are referring to.

> 6. Import my Macros

These come with the Normal template if that is where you have them stored. (not the best storage location IMO) See [Organizing Your Macros](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/OrganizeMacros.htm) by Word MVP Beth Melton.

> 7. I’ve been using DOCX and will this force a new file format on me?

Yes, and no. Word 2021 files are in .docx format. If you use your Word 2013 files, they will show in compatibility mode and be limited to Word 2013 features. They can be updated to the 2021 .docx format under File > Info > Convert. The same is true of the Normal.dotm template.

Comment: 2. Is wrong - You _can_ save all your files exclusively offline with Office 365 subscription. I am doing that for years; it is just a setting in the options (a bid hidden though). You are NOT forced to use or have a OneDrive.

Comment: Yes, **you can save** all files exclusively offline. However, **you cannot use Microsoft 365 completely offline**. *You must be connected to the Internet at least once every 30 days to validate/check the license and receive updates.* Office 2021 can be used completely offline.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this request (what should I do) is opinion, but not all.

1. Will you keep both version?  If you upgrade, no, you will just have the latest version.
2. One can use Office 365 with or without a Microsoft Account on the computer.  You need a Microsoft Account to purchase it and pay. To purchase from Microsoft the same would be true for Office 2021. It is best to use with a Microsoft account but it will work fine disconnected.
3. List item

In terms of File Saving, you can save your files locally, on a network, or One Drive - no requirement to use One Drive.

3. Yes. I have done that all the way along - Office 2002 to 365 and all versions.
4. Opinion. I customize the ribbon to 90% of my satisfaction but not perfect.
5. A certain amount of right click to perform actions and I use that. Right click for corrections is there as well.
6. May depend on the specific macro, but the answer is mostly yes.
7. You can still use DOC (and read write DOC) but most of use have gravitated to DOCX and that works fine.

I hope this helps you decide what to do.

Note: I use and like the subscription product Office 365 and that remains the overall leading Office suite from Microsoft.

Comment: The author is upgrading to Office 2021, not Office 365.  The author can have both Office 2013 and Office 2021 installed provided they are not the same bitness.  In this case, since Office 2013 by default was 32-bit and Office 2021 by default is 64-bit this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Office 2013 supported .docx and was the default file standard.  It was Office 2007 and earlier that used .doc instead of .docx. I also am not entirely sure how you use a subscription-based product like Office 365, that requires a Microsoft Account to be subscribed to, without logging into the account with the activated subscription.  *This answer has a lot of problems in my opinion.*

Answer (score 0):

> Will installing the 2021 version leave my previous installation of Microsoft Office Home and Student 2013 intact? It would be a big help in migration and give me a chance to fix what 2021 breaks.

What you want is not possible since both versions use the same Click-to-Run installer.

> If you have a Microsoft 365 subscription or non-subscription versions such as Office Home and Business 2021, 2019, 2016, or 2013, in most cases you can't run these versions together on the same computer.

Source: [Install and use different versions of Office on the same PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf)

> I understand you need a Microsoft Account to download it, but I want to use it completely offline and save all my files locally as I’ve been doing for the past 40 years.

OneDrive functionality is very pronounced in Office 2021.  However, you are NOT required to log into your Microsoft Account.  You can save files locally, Office 2021, will keep track of those local locations.  Of course, by default OneDrive saves files locally, they are just also synchronized, so you might find that you like that particular feature.

> Can I import and get all the customizations out of my 2013 Normal template?

**Office 2021 will accept an Office 2013 Normal template.**  Once you have loaded your template file you can convert it to the newer .docx standard.

Source: [Converting documents to a newer format](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-transfer-microsoft-word-macros-to-another-computer/)

> Will I be able to get my customizations, custom Ribbon tabs, and Ribbon groups?

They were very few changes to the functionality of the Ribbon between Office 2013 and Office 2021.  However, specific features within a given Office product could act differently.  You can of course import, your whatever changes you made, from Office 2013.

> Import my Macros

Any macros are connected to your `Normal.dotm` file.

Source: [How to transfer Microsoft Word macros to another computer](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-transfer-microsoft-word-macros-to-another-computer/)

> ’ve been using DOCX and will this force a new file format on me?

The current Word document file extension is .docx which means Office 2021 fully supports it.  Office 2019 introduced the newer .docx standard, Office 2013 does not have an issue opening it, you would just lose functionality unique to the newer versions of Word.

Comment: Definitely can open a document in the new .docx format in older versions of Word (Word 2007 and up, and 2003 with some extra coding). Features added after the version in which the document is opened will not work and the document when edited would be saved in the older version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer 2 questions above.

> > Will installing the 2021 version leave my previous installation of Microsoft Office Home and Student 2013 intact? It would be a big help in migration and give me a chance to fix what 2021 breaks.

I do not suggest install these 2 versions on the same computer. It's beset uninstall Office 2013 first.

These 2 versions both use C2R installation technology, but one version is 15.0, the another one is 16.0. We can't install two products of different versions together if both products use Click-to-Run as the installation technology and those products have overlapping Office applications.

Here is a [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20install%20two%20products%20together%20that%20have%20the%20same%20version%20but%20use%20different%20installation%20technologies.) and an article "[Install and use different versions of Office on the same PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf)" we can have a look.

> > I understand you need a Microsoft Account to download it, but I want to use it completely offline and save all my files locally, like I’ve been doing for the past 40 years.

There are links or methods to download Office packages that without logging into a Microsoft account.

But Office you want to upgrade is retail version, we need a Microsoft account to redeem a product key to activate it.

Once activated it, you can use it offline.

Answer (score -1):

Autosave is NOT available on 2021 unless you use the cloud.  This might be seen as a major drawback if you wish to keep your material solely on your computer.  It certainly affects me as I set autosave to 1 minute intervals after losing additionas to draft versions of a document over the years.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).